# How do I display a DevOps Dashboard on a TV?

Tags: azure-devops

I would like to display an Azure DevOps dashboard on a large format display using a headless appliance (Raspberry Pi?)

I can't find a way to automate the authentication or make the dashboard URL public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Azure DevOps (Cloud)**

Short answer: I believe, it is not possible.

Long answer: You can access data from Azure DevOps with a Personal Access Token (PAT), which includes dashboard data. However, only raw (json) data is accessible and not a rendered image or webpage. An example is given [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/dashboard/dashboards/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0).
See also: [How to create a PAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/pats?view=azure-devops)

**Azure DevOps Server (on-premise)**

Short answer: Windows yes, Linux maybe.

Long answer: Azure DevOps Server uses either Kerberos or NTLM authentication. On Windows, you are automatically authenticated without the need to enter a username and password (at least in Internet Explorer), if the device and user (or service account) are domain joined. Firefox needs some additional [config](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Integrated_authentication).

On Linux, you will not get automatic authentication out of the box. However, it might be possible to construct your own [NTLM-Authentication header](http://davenport.sourceforge.net/ntlm.html#ntlmHttpAuthentication) an send it via a Firefox Exteions.

Answer (score 0):

On the Cloud version of Azure DevOps, try the [Windows 10 accounts](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/windows-10-accounts/ppnbnpeolgkicgegkbkbjmhlideopiji) Chrome extension. You still need to authenticate manually once.